# Inserting data from two similar tables into one master table in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

- `Table1` -> Id, CountryFk, CompanyName
- `Table2` -> Id, CountryFk, CompanyName, Website

I need to merge `Table1` and `Table2` into 1 master table. I know this can be done by something like the below query -

```
   INSERT INTO masterTable(Id, CountryFk, CompanyName)
   SELECT * FROM Table1
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM Table2;
```

But, I have an extra column, `website` in `table2` which isn't there in `table1`. I need this column in `masterTable`.

And more importantly, `Table1` and `Table2` have repeating companies with the same `countryFK`. For eg, `IBM` at `countryFK=123` could be present twice in `Table1`. And `Table1` could have a `companyName` that is present in `Table2`.

For eg: `IBM` at `countryFk = 123` could be present in `table1` and `table2`. I need to make sure that the `masterTable` does not have any duplicate companies.

Please note that the companyname by itself need not be unique. `masterTable` *can* have `IBM` with `countryFK = 123` and `IBM` with `countryFk = 321`.

`masterTable` **cannot** have `IBM` with `countryFk=123` twice.

Comment: Could you post the table structure of your `masterTable`? Is the `Id` identity?

Comment: This isn't as simple as it seems. You need to define the semantics of the merge explicitly. *Which* `Id` do you want to keep if there is a duplicate on `CompanyName`. *Which* `CountryFk`? What if there is a duplicate row within `Table1` or `Table2`?

Comment: Id primary key in tables?

Comment: @FelixPamittan - the masterTable Id is identity.

Comment: @Ic Thanks. I did not take into consideration countryFk earlier. I have edited the question to include your comment.

Comment: @utility. yes Id is primary key in all the tables.

Comment: table2 has repeated country ?

Comment: @utility - table1 and table2 are dump data from two different sources. So we have repetitons. table2 can have "IBM" from countryfk=123 twice.

Comment: Do you need to keep the original id values from Table1 and Table2? if so, how do you decide what id to keep for multiple records with the same company name?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I dont need id values. The masterTable id column is an identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, if you need to ensure both `CompanyName` and `CountryFk` not duplicate in MasterTable, you should add an unique index on the column.

Below query selects all distinct value in Table1 and Table2, and insert with existence checking for both `CompanyName` and `CountryFk`.

```
-- Id is identity, no need to insert value
INSERT MasterTable (CountryFk, CompanyName, WebSite)
SELECT 
    CountryFk, 
    CompanyName,
    (
       SELECT TOP(1) WebSite FROM Table2 
       WHERE CompanyName = data.CompanyName  
           AND CountryFk = data.CountryFk 
           AND WebSite IS NOT NULL
    ) AS WebSite
FROM 
(
    SELECT CountryFk, CompanyName FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT CountryFk, CompanyName FROM Table2
) data
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM MasterTable 
        WHERE CompanyName = data.CompanyName AND CountryFk = data.CountryFk
    )
GROUP BY
    CountryFk, 
    CompanyName
```

Comment: Works fine. No duplicate records. Thanks Eric!

Answer (score 1):

This may work

```
INSERT INTO masterTable(Id, CountryFk, CompanyName,Website)
   SELECT Id, CountryFk, CompanyName, NULL as Website FROM Table1
   UNION
   SELECT Id, CountryFk, CompanyName,Website FROM Table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for proper `UNION`.

```
INSERT INTO masterTable(Id, CountryFk, CompanyName,Website)
   SELECT Id, CountryFk, CompanyName, "Website" as Website FROM Table1
   UNION
   SELECT Id, CountryFk, CompanyName, Website FROM Table2 WHERE CompanyName NOT IN(SELECT CompanyName FROM Table1);
```

**Or**

Once, you have merge your both table data into master table, then you can look for duplicate data and remove them

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CountryFk, CompanyName 
                                       ORDER BY ( SELECT 0)) RN
         FROM   MyTable)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  RN > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO masterTable(CountryFk, CompanyName, WebSite)
SELECT CountryFk, CompanyName, min(WebSite) 
  FROM Table2 
 group by CountryFk, CompanyName;
INSERT INTO masterTable(CountryFk, CompanyName)
SELECT distinct CountryFk, CompanyName
  FROM Table1 
  LEFT JOIN masterTable
    on masterTable.CountryFk = Table1.CountryFk 
   and masterTable.CompanyName = Table1.CompanyName 
 where masterTable.CountryFk is null;
```

Comment: This would not eliminate duplicates from within Table2 itself. Any duplicates with Table2 will be written to the master table. Any idea how we can workaround this?